# Sequence ajax call without "async:false" in each function

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am struggling with some functionalities in JQuery.

I need to run the ajax functions in sequential.

Here is my code

```
$.each([ 52, 97 ], function( index, value ) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "sample.php"
    }).then(function(msg) {
        alert('1');
        alert("msg");
        $.ajax({
            method:"post",
            url: "sample1.php",
            data:{name:value}
            }).then(function(msg1) {
                alert('2');
                alert("msg1");
        });
    });

});
```

For Eg. For now I get this result
[Please refer screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aDUPo.jpg)

I need to get like this [Need output like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SPoFd.jpg)

I am getting expected output with adding "async:false" but that was freeze the page in chrome and safari browser when I try to load large amount of data.

So Please help to solve this scenario.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Trying to get async operations to perform in a sync manner is akin to herding cats. It's best not to even try. I'd strongly suggest you put all data in to a *single* AJAX call. This has two benefits; you can be guaranteed of the order of receipt/response, and more importantly you're also not flooding your server with ***45 requests in less than a second***

Comment: My first ajax call results are the input to the second ajax call